# Calculation of common emitter output impedance with output resistance

Tags: impedance, common-emitter

[[image: CE]]

I don't understand why \$g_{m}\$ survives. Since \$v_{\pi}\$ is equivalent to \$\Delta V\$ , which is perturbation of signal, which is then set as AC ground. Doesn't that mean \$v_{\pi}= \Delta V = 0\$? Thus make \$g_{m}\$ open for calculation? How can I calculate the output impedance like so? With inspection method assuming \$g_{m}\$ is open, I'm getting \$R_{out} = ( r_{\pi} || R_{E} ) + r_{0} \$ also could you show how to calculate the input impedance as well?

Answer (score 1):

No.  What is happening here is the test voltage Vx will create a current Ix.  These are used to calculate the output impedance.  What you are not taking into consideration here is that Vx will cause a voltage change at node P.  Since the other end of r_pi is connected to ground, this cause a change in delta V.  Delta V is not zero.

Comment: What if R_o is not there? Then is g_m open in that case? Where I can define Delta V = v_pi as zero?

Comment: What means "not there"? Do you mean ro=0 or ro infinite? What menas "g_m "open"? Do you mean the current source? Please, be more exact - otherwise, we cannot answer.